# Use lapply to find if column names of various dataframes are the same

Tags: r, list, data.table, lapply

I am trying to find out  if the column names in about 20 data frames are the same. The 20 data frames are held in a list (`Portfolio_snapshots`). Here is a sample set of data:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10),v2=LETTERS[1:5])
DF2 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10),v2=LETTERS[1:5])
DF3 <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(10),v3=LETTERS[1:5])
Portfolio_snapshots <- list(DF1,DF2,DF3)
```

I've tried this:

```
Df_names <- lapply(Portfolio_snapshots, function(x) {
        names(as.data.table(x))})
lapply(Df_names,function(x) {all.equal((Df_names[1]),(x))})
```

But it doesn't produce the right result . The code should ideally produce a `TRUE` for first two and a `FALSE` for the third.  Also if there is any way to show which are the column names where there is a mismatch,  then that would be an added bonus.

Comment: and your question might be?

Comment: Try wrapping `all.equal` with `isTRUE` if you only want a TRUE/FALSE answer

Comment: I tried this lapply(Df_names,function(x) {isTRUE(all.equal((Df_names[1]),(x)))}) however, it shows a FALSE for all 20 comparisons, whereas atleast the first one should be TRUE, as it is comparing Df_names[1] to itself.

Comment: You're not getting a good answer because you haven't given us a simple reproducible example

Comment: you can use `setdiff` in r `setdiff(names(df1),names(df2),names(df3))`

Comment: added a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out Reduce(intersect,Df_names) is a good solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but this works:

`apply(do.call(rbind,lapply(Portfolio_snapshots,colnames)),2,function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1)`

This basically creates a vector of names for each dataframe and column and sees if there's more than one unique name. 
It will return a boolean value for each column, `TRUE` if the names differ and `FALSE` if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This comparison shows which variables are mismatches:

```
library(janitor)
x <- compare_df_cols(DF1, DF2, DF3)
x

  column_name       DF1       DF2       DF3
1          v1   numeric   numeric   numeric
2          v2 character character      <NA>
3          v3      <NA>      <NA> character
```

As to labeling the clusters of data.frames: it's hard to say which group would be `TRUE` or `FALSE` in a larger case but you could group them by sets of columns present in each data.frame and look at the sizes of those groups:

```
library(tidyverse)
x %>%
  select(-column_name) %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble(rownames = "df") %>%
  pivot_longer(V1:V3) %>%
  group_by(df) %>%
  summarise(var_types = paste(value, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  group_by(var_types) %>%
  mutate(group_id = cur_group_id(),
         group_size = n())

# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   var_types [2]
  df    var_types              group_id group_size
  <chr> <chr>                     <int>      <int>
1 DF1   numeric, character, NA        1          2
2 DF2   numeric, character, NA        1          2
3 DF3   numeric, NA, character        2          1
```

Group #1, containing `DF1` and `DF2`, is the largest.